# Using awk to print lines with a column matching certain characters

Tags: awk

I want awk to print the line if the first two characters in field 7 are "R ".
I tried this command and it didn't work:

```
cat file.txt | awk -F, '{if($7=="R *") print $0}'
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: An explanation of *HOW* it didn't work would be more helpful than "it didn't work".

Comment: `==` doesn't pattern match. You want a patter match use `~` or use `==` and a substring of the field.

Answer (score 1):

Use the tilde sign and Regular Expressions (words that start with the letter 'R' and second is space)

```
cat file.txt | awk -F, '{if ($7 ~ /^R /) print $0;}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, '$7 ~ /^[ \t]*R /' file.txt
```

Assuming data are comma separated.